# pushing content to social sites like facebook, twitter linkedin, youtube and vimeo

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

I have custom build cms in wich I want to enable the content editors to push content to social media sites.

The idea is as follows: Content editor creates article in cms and selects some check boxes to indicate where the content should be pushed. for example Facebook and twitter.

My controller processes the request and based on user selections pushes the content to the relevant social sites.

I understand that spring social provides functionality to interact with with social media sites but all examples are base on integrating some futures of these social media sites in to your own site. Like connecting with friends and stuff. 
I am not looking for this. I just want to push content to media sites.

If anyone can point in the right direction on how to achieve this I would be very grateful. I am curently using spring, spring mvc, spring data jpa with hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

You need an account to push the content to. You need to authenticate (with OAuth) these accounts and then use the spring-social API (and the youtube and vimeo APIs) to push the content.

You can't just send it without having a user on the target site.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I want to push to my accounts on the relevant social sites. Anyway you are saying that I can still use spring social to achieve this, together with viemo an youtube APIs?

Comment: ok, thanks... I am still browsing the documentation. trying to figure this out.

Comment: I have to ask because I am stuck, have you ever used spring social in this way?

Comment: yes. There is not difference. You connect your account through an admin interface (via oauth) and then start sending the content

Comment: yes, but from what i see in the spring doc example there is an httpservlet response involved in the oauth steps. please take a look at this thread: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?125913-spring-social-console-application-with-main-method

Comment: there are multiple authentication options in OAuth. One is using a authentication code rather than redirecting the user to your site